# Is there some log console for Selenium Webdriver in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I want to know if there is some log console or some log error trace in Eclipse for Selenium. I'm using it with Java and functions of JavaScript and JQuery and I don't have any idea about how to access to the log console, if it is possible.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much!

EDIT: I'm using my Webdriver using Google Chrome and not Firefox as JAL puts in his comments.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Logging

Comment: I saw both pages before but I don't understand how to apply them into my project. Anyway, I need it for Chrome, not for Firefox, I edit my question now.